# Font size and control sizes are bigger when porting windows phone 8.1 silverlight code to Windows 10 mobile UWP app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I tried porting my entire windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app to windows mobile 10 uwp (universal) app, I see that the control size has increased a lot and even the fonts are bigger, Do we need to adjust the font size and control sizes when porting the apps from Silverlight phone 8.1 to uwp(universal) windows mobile 10?

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtle differences between 8.1 and UWP as explained
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188204.aspx). For instance, the font size you refer to has to do with the view pixel now being abstracted in 'effective pixels' or epx in UWP. The link and links therein provide all the answers.

Comment: How about control size? how should we modify the control size so that the application look and feel remains the same?